# Java sockets multitasking

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, multitasking

A server sockets accepts connections from clients and assigns each of them a thread to work on. **Inside each of those threads** I'm going to listen for incoming requests from the client represented by the current thread and then I'm going to process that request and wait again for other requests. Requests are basically strings sent using

```
DataOutputStream.writeUTF(String string)
```

So basically the thread "sleeps" until the client sends a request.

PS: Requests can and will require to do multiple data transfers before completing it, it could also take a quite long amount of time.
For example:
The client wants to log in, great, he sends the server a request, so basically he's writing an UTF to the socket that could look something like

```
dataOutputStream.writeUTF("login");
```

Now the client will send the username and password as well

```
dataOutputStream.writeUTF("hellix08");
dataOutputStream.writeUTF("somePassword");
```

The **server** thread associated with that client reads the first UTF

```
switch(dataInputStream.readUTF()){
    case "login":
        //Do login
        break;
    case "doSomethingElse":
        //Do something else
        break;
}
```

now he knows the client wants to login, great, he knows another 2 strings are in the stream and reads them, then he checks whether they're correct or not and replies back with something like a boolean

```
switch(dataInputStream.readUTF()){
    case "login":
        String username = dataInputStream.readUTF();
        String password = dataInputStream.readUTF();
        dataOutputStream.writeBoolean(isValid(username,password));
        break;
    case "doSomethingElse":
        //Do something else
        break;
}
```

What I've tried to explain here is: requests usually requires some communication, I can't just read all strings and send them to worker threads because if those threads were to read from the stream simultaneously, they would end up reading garbage. Now, this switch solution would actually be fine, I don't use threads, the stream is read nice and clean, and everything works just fine because this kind of request is *fast*.

But I have another other big problem, and that's that some of those requests could require some time to be completed, for example one of those requests will be a request of file transfer, this makes everything more difficult because I can't just use the switch and monothread every request because other requests are going to wait for it to finish and this can be a slow process. This is fine for normal client requests because, it would be ok to say "Well you can't do that right now, I'm already sending you a file, wait a minute..." but here it comes the annoying bit:

While the server thread is doing things with the client, I want a shell on the server (Running on a separate thread and one only, not one for every client, and also only available for system admins), and that shell shall communicate with the client, for example I might want to ping a client, drop its connection from the server, require to login again and so on and so forth. Things that an admin could type it at any time.

Now the thing is that just with client requests, these shell requests could be complex, requiring multiple data transfers or long periods of time and it's pretty obvious that they could easily mess up with client requests just because **I can only use 1 stream**

If I want to ping a client for example, by sending some data and expecting the client to respond, then the data going towards the client would mess up the file reading from the stream.

```
ClientA requests file transfer
Server "Ok"
Server: Starting file transfer...
Server: Sent 786 bytes out of 3953
ClientA: Read 786 bytes out of 3953
Server: Sent 1245 bytes out of 3953
ClientA: Read 1245 bytes out of 3953

ServerShell: Pinging ClientA, sending some data
Server: Sent 1987 bytes out of 3953

ClientA: "Wtf is this mess of bytes"
```

I would like to make ClientRequests and ShellRequests indipendent from each other, so that they run simultaneously and don't mess up each others' things.

This pretty much sums up what I'm trying to do. This looks like something you see happening in every days programs, if I'm on steam I can chat, download games and play multiplayer games at the same time. Still I have no clue how to do it, based on replies and googling I've came up with some ideas but for one reason or another they're always useless or they have major flaws.

Thanks

Comment: The client only has one connection. It can send as many requests down that connection as it likes, but those requests have to be sequential, not concurrent, because the connection is sequential, not concurrent. If a client wants to do two or more things concurrently it should open two or more connections.

Comment: How do I open new connections?

Comment: Same way you opened the first one.

Comment: But how do I make sure the connection is coming from the same client?

Comment: By its remote IP address.